# How to convert string (char*) to number with error checking using standard library functions?

Tags: c++, string, int, type-conversion

I can think of 2 ways to convert a string to `int`: `strtol` and `std::stringstream`. The former doesn't report errors (if string is not a representation of a number), the latter throws an exception BUT it is too relaxed. An example:

```
std::wstring wstr("-123a45");
int result = 0;
try { ss >> result; }
catch (std::exception&) 
{
   // error handling
}
```

I want to detect an error here because the whole string is not convertible to int, but no exception is being thrown and result is set to -123.
How can I solve my task using standard C++ facilities?

Comment: [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) does report the termination point. if the terminating char that stopped the parse isn't what you deem appropriate, you can handle it as an error condition. Ex. If it supposed to be a *complete* number and *doesn't* terminate on the null-char, consider it an error. If you are parsing "123 + 456" and it doesn't terminate on whitespace or an operator, its an error, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), or [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol).

The first throws an exception (and is in C++11 and later), the other you have to manually check (as it's originally a standard C function).

And you can indeed use `std::strtol` to check that a string is a valid number:

```
char some_string[] = "...";

char *endptr;
long value = std::strtol(some_string, &endptr, 10);

if (endptr == some_string)
{
    // Not a valid number at all
}
else if (*endptr != '\0')
{
    // String begins with a valid number, but also contains something else after the number
}
else
{
    // String is a number
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use `stoi` on all the platforms I'm targeting. `strtol` does not report as I've mentioned in the question. Any other options?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Just updated my answer with how you can use `strtol` to check for valid numbers.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Indeed there is: [`std::wcstol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcstol).

Answer (score 8):

You erroneously believe that `strtol()` does not provide error checking, but that is not true. The second parameter to `strtol()` can be used to detect if the entire string was consumed.

```
char *endptr;
int result = strtol("-123a45", &endptr, 10);
if (*endptr != '\0') {
    /*...input is not a decimal number */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, you could convert to an int, and then convert that back into a wstring, and check the strings for equality.

Not a good idea for doubles, and you would probably need to trim the input string of whitespace even for ints.